# Rigorous description of the asymptotics for $\operatorname{erfi}(z)$ as $|z|\to\infty$

Tags: complex-analysis, asymptotics, error-function

According to [Wolfram functions](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Erfi/06/02/0001/), the imaginary error function admits an asymptotic expansion for $|z|\to\infty$ of the form
$$
\tag{1}
\operatorname{erfi}(z)\sim\frac{z}{\sqrt{-z^2}}+\frac{e^{z^2}}{\sqrt\pi z}{_2F_0}\left({1,\frac{1}{2}\atop -};\frac{1}{z^2}\right).
$$
Here, the hypergeometric function converges nowhere and should be understood as a formal description of a divergent asymptotic series.

**I am looking for a rigorous derivation of this asymptotic expansion and, in particular, and explanation of where the $z/\sqrt{-z^2}$ term comes from.**

Searching this site I came across [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2862797/asymptotic-expansion-of-erfix) answer stating
$$
\operatorname{erfi}(z)\sim i+\frac{e^{z^2}}{\sqrt\pi z}{_2F_0}\left({1,\frac{1}{2}\atop -};\frac{1}{z^2}\right),
$$
which disagrees with $(1)$ since $z/\sqrt{-z^2}=\pm i$ with the sign depending on the argument of $z$. In either case, I also find is curious that the asymptotic expansion has a complex component even if $z\in\Bbb R$.

Further research indicates that the discrepancy here is due to the [Stokes phenomenon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes_phenomenon), which causes the asymptotic behavior of functions to differ depending on the region of the complex plane $z$ resides; however, I am still unsure as to how this phenomenon specifically applies to $\operatorname{erfi}(z)$. Can someone please explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From $\operatorname{erf}(z)=1-\operatorname{erfc}(z)$ and [$\S7.12(\text{i})$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/7.12.i) in the DLMF, it follows that
$$
\operatorname{erf}(z) \sim 1 - \frac{{\mathrm{e}^{ - z^2 } }}{{\sqrt \pi  }}\sum\limits_{m = 0}^\infty  {( - 1)^m \frac{{\left( {\frac{1}{2}} \right)_m }}{{z^{2m + 1} }}} 
$$
if $z\to \infty$ and $\operatorname{Re}(z)>0$, and
$$
\operatorname{erf}(z) \sim  - 1 - \frac{{\mathrm{e}^{ - z^2 } }}{{\sqrt \pi  }}\sum\limits_{m = 0}^\infty  {( - 1)^m \frac{{\left( {\frac{1}{2}} \right)_m }}{{z^{2m + 1} }}} 
$$
if $z\to \infty$ and $\operatorname{Re}(z)<0$. The positive and negative imaginary axes are Stokes lines. On the Stokes lines, the correct expansion is the average of the expansions on the two sides, i.e.,
$$
\operatorname{erf}(z) \sim  - \frac{{\mathrm{e}^{ - z^2 } }}{{\sqrt \pi  }}\sum\limits_{m = 0}^\infty  {( - 1)^m \frac{{\left( {\frac{1}{2}} \right)_m }}{{z^{2m + 1} }}} 
$$
if $z\to \infty$ and $\operatorname{Re}(z)=0$. Since $\operatorname{erfi}(z)=-\mathrm{i}\operatorname{erf}(\mathrm{i}z)$, we can infer that
$$
\operatorname{erfi}(z) \sim \operatorname{sgn}(\operatorname{Im}(z))\mathrm{i} + \frac{{\mathrm{e}^{z^2 } }}{{\sqrt \pi  }}\sum\limits_{m = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{\left( {\frac{1}{2}} \right)_m }}{{z^{2m + 1} }}} 
$$
as $z\to \infty$, with the usual convention that $\operatorname{sgn}(0)=0$.