Asymptotic Expansion of $I(z) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-t^2}}{(z-t)} dt $ and Stoke Lines
Question: as in the title, I need to find the asymptotic expansion of:
$$I(z) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-t^2}}{(z-t)} dt $$
where $\operatorname{Im}(z)<0$ as $z\to\infty$, and its analytic continuation to $\operatorname{Im}(z)\ge 0$. Finally, find the Stoke lines.
My attempt: I tried to put the integral in an appropriate form to use Watson's lemma, so I set $t^2 = |z|u$, and get:
$$ I = \frac{|z|^{\frac{1}{2}}}{2z} \int_0^\infty u^{\frac{-1}{2}} \left(1-\frac{|z|^{1/2}}{z} u^{1/2}\right)^{-1} e^{-|z|u} du $$
Then:
$$f(u):= u^{\frac{-1}{2}} \left(1-\frac{|z|^{1/2}}{z} u^{1/2}\right)^{-1}$$
has a series expansion as $u \to 0^+$, so using Watson's lemma, I got:
$$ I = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2} |z|^{-\frac{n+1}{2}} e^{-i(n+1)\theta} \Gamma\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right) x^{-\frac{n+1}{2}} $$
where $z:=|z|e^{i\theta}$.
My questions: (1) if my calculations were correct, I could not see how this integral is related to $\operatorname{Im}(z)<0$ i.e. $-\pi < \theta < 0$, as I didn't put any constraint on $\theta$ throughout my calculations.
(2) I also wanted to ask when Watson's lemma is applicable: let $F(x) = \int_0^T f(t) e^{-xt} dt$ where $f(x)$ is some function satisfying certain conditions, $f(x)$ is allowed to be complex-valued right? I think this is true, but since it isn't explicitly said anywhere, I was hoping to verify that this indeed is true.
Thank you!

For question (2) the answer is yes. See e.g. Miller's Applied Asymptotic Analysis.

Initially, you have to decide on which side of the pole at $z$ are you going to integrate when $\operatorname{Im}(z)<0$. Then apply Watson's lemma. The analytic continuation to $\operatorname{Im}(z)\ge 0$ follows by deforming the contour through the pole and picking up the residue (which is exactly the discontinuity coming from the Stokes phenomenon).

Also, a better way to do this is by letting $t = zs$ and hence $$
I(z) = \int_{ - \infty }^{ + \infty } {\frac{{{\rm e}^{ - z^2 s^2 } }}{{1 - s}}{\rm d}s}
$$ where we integrate above or below the pole at $s=1$. Regard $z^2$ as the large variable.

@Gary Thank you!

$$\int \frac{e^{-t^2}}{(z-t)}\,dt=-\int \frac{e^{-(x+z)^2}}{x}\,dx=$$
If $z$ is a complex, then
$$I(z) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{e^{-t^2}}{(z-t)}\,dt=\pi \, e^{-z^2}\, (\text{erfi}(z)+i)$$
$$I(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\Gamma \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{ z^{2 n+1}}$$

Your asymptotic expansion is not valid for all large complex $z$. More precisely: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4396217
