# Prove $ \operatorname{erfi}(x) \in O(e^{x^2})$

Tags: asymptotics, error-function

How can we prove:
$$
\operatorname{erfi}(x) \in O (e^{x^2})
$$

Samely we can prove:
$$
\lim_{ x \rightarrow \infty  } \frac {\int_0^x e^{t^2} \, dt} {e^{x^2}} = 0
$$

Also it is so awkward. The integral of a function should be greater than or equal to that function in growth rate but here it seems like it is the opposite.
By the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/58899/435068), we can observe this, but it's still vague that how that answer is achieved.
It's important to mention that the relations mentioned are all achieved via WolframAlpha.

Comment: "The integral of a function should be greater than or equal to that function but here it seems like it is the opposite" — I can see where intuition would lead you to this, but the point here is that $e^{x^2}$ grows _so_ quickly that it outpaces its accumulated integral 'up to' that point. The exponential function is (sometimes derfinitionally!) the balancing point there, in that its growth is exactly fast enough to keep up with its integral (up to the requisite constant); anything that grows faster than that will outgrow its integral.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio It's easy to prove it that way.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Great that's the intuition I needed.
An answer that sums up these to comment would be nice so I can select it as the solution.

Comment: Converted my comment into an answer!

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Don't you mind demonstrate it mathematically via Hopital as the first comment say? So it can be complete enough to be the solution.

Comment: Ahhh! Yes, point. I'll try and add that shortly.

Answer (score 1):

You say that 'the integral of a function should be greater than or equal to that function but here it seems like it is the opposite'; the idea that an integral is bigger than the function itself is intuitive, but $e^{x^2}$ grows so quickly that it outpaces its accumulated integral up to whatever point of evaluation. The exponential function is (sometimes definitionally!) the balancing point with respect to rate of growth; it grows exactly fast enough to keep up with its integral, up to the requisite constant. Anything that grows faster than $e^x$ will outgrow its integral in the same way that $e^{x^2}$ does.